# Сохранение изображения С#

Tags: c#, изображения

Всем Привет!
Этот кусок кода сохраняет pictureBox1 и textBox1 в картинку при нажатии клавиши и выкладывает это в корень папки программы. Хочу реализовать сохранение с указанием места и формата....

```
private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var res1 = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;
    var res2 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox1.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, 100, 100);

    string savepath = "image.png";

    Merge(res1, res2).Save(savepath);
}
```

Comment: Хочешь - прекрасно. А в чем вопрос?) Покажи наработки и что именно у тебя не получается. Пока что видно лишь желание что бы тебе сделали и поднесли на тарелочке, а не то что ты сам пытался что-либо сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться [диалогом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=net-5.0). Вот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067676/11837368):

```
    using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        dialog.FilterIndex = 2 ;
        dialog.RestoreDirectory = true ;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var savepath = dialog.FileName;
            
            // Сохраняете как в вашем коде
        }
    }
```